# Spring boot Rest Endpoint is not accessible from Angular application in GKE within same pod

Tags: angular, spring-boot, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running an angular app with backend rest service from spring boot on Kubernetes in Google Cloud.
The angular app tries to consume data from spring rest endpoint like:

Spring boot endpoint: http://localhost:8080/app/getDetails

This endpoint works well as if I do port forward it runs. If I expose the endpoint explicitly from service using ingress, it is accessible too.

But it is not accessible from Angular application running in the same pod as different container hosted inside nginx. (Cors is enabled)

From console it shows :

GET http://localhost:8080/app/getDetails net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Error: [object ProgressEvent]

Any idea how to get through this?

Here is my angular code

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  private url: string = "http://localhost:8080/app/getDetails";

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  dtls: any;

  ngOnInit() {}

  public onClick() {
    this.httpClient.get(this.url).subscribe(
      results => {
        this.dtls = results;
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log("Error: " + err.error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Here is nginx.conf

```
upstream webapp {
        server 127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

Deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp-demo
  labels:
    app: myapp-dtls-demo
spec:
  containers:
  - name: myapp-ui
    image: myuser/myapp-kubernetes-demo
    ports:
    - name: ui-port
      containerPort: 80
  - name: myapp-api
    image: myuser/myapp-service-kubernetes-demo
```

Service.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp-demo-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 4200
    targetPort: ui-port
    name: ui
    protocol: TCP   
  selector:
    app: myapp-football-demo
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Comment: Angular applications don't run in a pod. They run in your browser, on your machine: Angular is a **client-side** framework. localhost is your own computer, but the server runs in the cloud, i.e. on a Google server.

Comment: Thanks.So to access it from Angular application, how to access the endpoint? I thought within same pod it can communicates each other using localhost.

Comment: I don't know anything about google cloud and kubernetes, but you typically configure nginx to act as a reverse proxy for API URLs (i.e. forward requests to /api to the backend Spring server), and simply use local URLs (i.e. `/app/getDetails` instead of `http://localhost:8080/app/getDetails`) to send requests to serving the angular application.

Comment: I'm facing similar issue, can yu share any examples please for configuring reverse proxy